# Unable to Mock WebClient, calls the external API without mocking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have a service which calls an external API and maps into a list of entities (which is another entity). To create Unit test cases, I have created a json file with the required output and mapped it there.

The service had initially used RestTemplate and I was able to mock it easily with the same code but then I had to change it to WebClient to make it synchronous, But now it's not mocking the WebClient and leads to the external API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I haven't put out the whole code as I'm facing issues in WebClient specifically, the same unit test had passed when I used RestTemplate

I understand MockWebServer would be easier but I'm looking for solutions in WebClient if possible

**EntityService.java**

```
public Mono<List<EntityDTO>> getNumber(String Uri) {

return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(Uri)
        .build()
        .get()
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(EntityDTO.class))
        .flatMapMany(dto -> Flux.fromIterable(dto.getEntityDetails()))
        .map(this::getEntityDTO)
        .collectList();}
```

**EntityServiceTest.java**

```
 @Test
 void shouldReturnEntities() throws IOException {
    ServiceInstance si = mock(ServiceInstance.class);
    String exampleRequest =new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("entityPath/entitytest.json")));
        
ClientResponse response = ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .body(exampleRequest)
                        .build();

Entity entity = Entity.builder().id("1").name("test")).build
                  
when(si.getServiceId()).thenReturn("external-api");
when(discoveryClient.getInstances(anyString())).thenReturn(List.of(si));            
when(webClientBuilder.build().get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
when(requestHeadersUriSpec.exchange()).thenReturn(Mono.just(response));
when(entityRepository.findById(eq(entity.getId()))).thenReturn(Optional.of(entity));

Flux<EntityDTO> entityNumbers = entityService.getEntityNumbers(entity.getId(),0,1).
StepVerifier.create(entityNumbers).expectNext(entity).verifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: With `when(webClientBuilder.build().get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);` you are trying to mock two methods at on time. Should be `when(webClientBuilder.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);`. If you have to mock `when(webClientBuilder.build()).then???;` please add an additional mock-Statement.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking WebClient could be very tricky and error-prone. Even if you could cover some simple positive cases, it would be very hard to test more complex scenarios, like error handling, retries, ...

I would recommend [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) which provides a very good API for testing web clients. Here are some examples

```
stubFor(get("/api")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(...)
        )
);
```

You could easily test both positive and negative scenarios by providing different stubs

```
stubFor(get("/api")
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withStatus(500)
        )
);
```

or test retry logic using [Scenarios](https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) or even simulate timeouts using [Delays](https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/).